# How can I lint a C file?

Tags: formatting, c

I have the following:

```
int main()
{

  int a = 1;
      int b = 2;
  return 0;
};
```

I am expecting some lint to align the indentation.  My file is open with `(C/*l AC Abbrev)`.

I try `C-c .` which asks me:

> Which C/*l indentation style?

I select `k&r` and hit enter.  Then nothing happens.  I try the others, `awk`, or `python`, and same thing, no linting occurs to tab the `int b` back over.  When I try again with `C-c .` it asks again but never lints my code.

What should I do to get formatting in C in emacs?

Answer (score 1):

`C-c .` just sets the formatting style to use when indenting the code, it doesn't actually change the indentation of anything the buffer. You can change the indentation of a region with the `indent-region` command, bound by default to `C-M-\`. `c-mode` also has the `c-indent-exp` command that indents an expression; this is handy for multi-line expressions near the cursor. `TAB` is bound to `c-indent-line-or-region`, which will reindent the current line should it be out of place. It also reindents regions like `C-M-\`, which is a little unusual. Most modes leave them separate.